# Paging with Spring and Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, pagination, paging

I have a screen and a report showing what error codes it is getting based on the virtual number selected on this page. I want to paginate the records in the report but this code is not working. What is my mistake here, how can I fix it?

```
    private static final String PAGINATION_SQL = " OFFSET ? ROW FETCH FIRST ? ROW ONLY";
    private static final String[] ERROR_TYPE  = new String[] {"BARRING", "UNKNOWN_NO", "NOTIYS", "SISERROR","REJECT","OTHER"};
    private static final String ERROR_REPORT_SQL = "WITH ERROR_CODE_VR AS ({0}) SELECT * FROM ERROR_CODE_VR WHERE ERROR_CODE_VR.COUNT != 0 ORDER BY ERROR_CODE_VR.COMPANY_MSISDN DESC";
    private static final String ERROR_REPORT_SQL_PART = "SELECT {0} as ERROR_DETAIL, {1} AS TARIFF, @REPORT_TABLE_NAME@.TARIH, @REPORT_TABLE_NAME@.COMPANY_MSISDN, SUM(@REPORT_TABLE_NAME@.{2}

public List<Report> getErrorCodeReport(ReportRequest request) {
        try {
            String innerSqlPart = "";
            for (String errorStr: Arrays.asList(ERROR_TYPE)) {
                innerSqlPart += MessageFormat.format(ERROR_REPORT_SQL_PART, '\''+errorStr + '\'', '\''+request.getTariff() + '\'', errorStr, "('"+request.getVirtualNumber()+"')");
                if(!errorStr.equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR_TYPE[ERROR_TYPE.length-1])) {
                    innerSqlPart += " UNION ALL ";
                }
            }
            String generatedSQL = generateUnionAllSql(innerSqlPart, request.getVirtualNumber());
            String errorReportSql = MessageFormat.format(ERROR_REPORT_SQL, generatedSQL);
            return this.JdbcTemplate.query(errorReportSql + PAGINATION_SQL, new Object[] { PAGE_RECORD_COUNT * request.getPageNumber(), PAGE_RECORD_COUNT}, new ErrorReportRowMapper());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("getErrorCodeReport virtualNumber:{}  {}",request.getVirtualNumber(), ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generated query, because a quick look at your code may me think it's like

```
SELECT ...
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
OFFSET ...
```

but it should be like

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ...
)
OFFSET ...
```